# Request.getAttribute is not working in jsp

Tags: jsp

I am setting  attribute inside form tag in jsp like this.

```
            request.setAttribute("iTDay", 5);
```

I am trying to retrieve the value as

```
             System.out.println( request.getAttribute("iTDay"));
```

in another jsp page. Simple but its not working. Kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you store the attribute in a session or redirect to the another page along with the attribute you cant retrieve the set attribute from one page to the another .

try

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("iTDay", 5);

System.out.println( request.getSession().getAttribute("iTDay"));
```

instead !

Comment: Yes i tried with session its working. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Can you please explain the reason for not working in request.

Comment: this might help  http://www.google.co.in/url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol&sa=U&ei=5BYFUZurNIvkrAeGt4GwAQ&ved=0CCUQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNEuzOJmaHHhiAYozsd68mxy9uDgIQ

Comment: No need for a vague link. The explanation is extremely simple: the other JSP is requested by another HTTP request than the one in which you've set the attribute!

Comment: @BalusC and pramod Thanks for the suggestions it is clear now.